# How can you return a List of List<String> From Android Room DAO query

Tags: android, android-room

My current Android application employs Room to manage the apps local database.

One of my tables holds a `List` of `String`s and I provide a `TypeConverter` which is working fine.

I no wish to have a adda Query that returns all this `List` of `String`s column for all rows of data.

My Room `DAO` query resembles this

```
@Query("SELECT myList from my_table")
fun selectListofList(): List<List<String>>
```

My type converter resembles this:-

```
import androidx.room.TypeConverter
import kotlinx.serialization.decodeFromString
import kotlinx.serialization.encodeToString
import kotlinx.serialization.json.Json

class StringListListTypeConverter {

    @TypeConverter
    fun stringToListList(value: String): List<List<String>> {
        return Json.decodeFromString(value)
    }

    @TypeConverter
    fun listListToString(value: List<List<String>>): String {
        return Json.encodeToString(value)
    }
}
```

I have mentioned this `TypeConverter` in my `@Database` abstract class

However my build fails as follows:-

```
MytDAO.java:41: error: Not sure how to convert a Cursor to this method's return type (java.util.List<java.util.List<java.lang.String>>).
    public abstract java.util.List<java.util.List<java.lang.String>> selectListofList();
```

How can I get Room to return a `List<List<String>>`